# Krita outdated version in ubuntu-disco-universe

Tags: software-center

Good night everyone,

I just reinstalled ubuntu 19.04 from scratch because I was having problems with it. In the Ubuntu software center, there are two options to install Krita, one from the snap store, and other from the ubuntu-disco-universe. Before I reinstalled ubuntu, I had Krita installed from the disco-universe source, assuming that this 2nd source hasn't changed in reinstallation. Now, after reinstallation, this second source has Krita 4.1 and not 4.2, which is the latest version, but before reinstallation, this second source had the latest Krita. Is there a way to update this ubuntu-disco-universe repository, so it has the newest version?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=krita shows versions for each release, https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/krita shows version for 19.04/disco.  You possibly didn't install from a Ubuntu official source  (eg. 3rd party ppa etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's likely that you had the snap installed rather than the debian package, or that you [added the ppa](https://krita.org/en/download/krita-desktop/).

The Ubuntu online package listing shows that the version in cosmic was 4.1.5, see the [Krita package listing for cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&searchon=names&keywords=krita).  So it's not possible that this would have gone backwards, since all package numbers *must* go forwards (or stay the same) during an upgrade.

The snap, however, is at 4.2 [as listed by snapcraft (see top-right)](https://snapcraft.io/krita).

[image].

Even then, the package was released less than a month ago, so I'm leaning towards you having added the ppa, since upstream ppas are always ahead of every other distribution method.

Comment: Good catch on the likely snap/deb confusion. Also, a deb of 4.2.1 has been packaged for Ubuntu 19.10, which will be released in October 2019. Users need not wait - anyone can install the snap today and always have the latest version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very complete reply. I don't know exactly what happened but is reassuring to know that my repositories are working as they're supposed to. I'll try to install Krita from the PPA. Have a great night, everyone.